# imagettftext Renders font differently

Tags: php, azure, imagettftext

I've created these countdown timers using imagettftext 
 [image: countdown timers]

The issue I have is the top version is on an Apache server and renders the font correctly, but the bottom version, on a Microsoft Azure server is using exactly the same code is rendering it slightly differently.
If you compare the 0 and 5 you should see what I mean.

Can anyone offer any help on why they should differ?

Comment: Different systems will render font differently, especially for small font size. You can try rendering with a higher density and scale down to the desired size after that.

Comment: What font you are using?